# Need some help manipulating a string in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, regex, c#-4.0, marc

I have a very large string that I am trying to convert from an old standard to marc21 xml standard.

The following line of code:

```
temp1 = inputString.Replace("<marc:controlfield tag=\"LDR\">", "<marc:leader>");
```

Produces the following:

```
<marc:leader>^^^^^nam^a22^^^^^3a^4500</marc:controlfield>
```

The problem is quite evident.

I perform a blanket conversion on a particular term and replace it with 'marc:controlfield'. Towards the end of my conversion process, I start to handle the leader element. Which is where I am right now. The xml savvy of out there know that:

```
</marc:controlfield>
```

needs to be:

```
</marc:leader>
```

Once this is done, my string can be tested for well formedness and validity and etc. I am struggling on how to grab the closing brackets for a leader element and replace it with xml as shown above.

Originally the Leader element looks like:

```
<fixfield id="LDR">^^^^^nam^a22^^^^^3a^4500</fixfield>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Regex:

```
strResult = Regex.Replace(inputString,
                          "<marc:controlfield tag=\"LDR\">([^<]*)</marc:controlfield>",
                          "<marc:leader>$1</marc:leader>");
```

explain:

```
[^<]*  

means any character except: '<' 
(0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)
```

Comment: Seems like Reg Expressions are the way to go! Will check this out tomorrow and will let you know if it works or not.

Comment: you got a website or a blog? I always got Regex problems - could do with a friendly neighbourhood regex person? =p

Answer (score 0):

maybe i'm just not understanding you correctly, but why wouldn't running

```
temp1 = temp1 .Replace("</marc:controlfield>", "</marc:leader>");
```

after your first conversion work for you?

Comment: reason being is that it will alter the closing tags for other controlfields. Which is not what I want. I just need to handle the marc leader element specially and I chose to do it last!